# Grab x amount of records from MySQL and get duplicates if not enough

Tags: mysql

Not really sure how to do this, but is it possible in one query to fetch x amount of records from a table, and if not enough is found, it will just randomly select duplicates.

I have a photos table, let's say it has 5 records in it, and I want to pull out 10 records and order them randomly, so I have something like:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 10
```

This will just pull back 5 randomly, cos that is all I have in the table. Can I tell MySQL, hey, if you find less than 10, just randomly grab more until you reach that number?

Any help appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: You could probably find a hack to do this, but it's not really what SQL and DBs are for. If you need to fill 10 items, can't you repeat some logic in your application if you have less that 10 records?

Comment: Yeah I can definitely do that, just was curious if this was possible with MySQL directly, I'll do it in my app if not.

Comment: I won't tell you it's not possible, just that I don't see any point or advantage to doing it in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
select * from Table1
union all
select * from 
(
  select * from 
  (
    select * from Table1 limit 10
    union all
    select * from Table1 limit 10
    union all
    select * from Table1 limit 10
    union all
    select * from Table1 limit 10
    -- more unions...
  ) t2 order by rand()
) rand_ordered
limit 10
```

Union the table for as many times as your number of needed records is (10 times in this example) to make it work with only one row in the table, order the result by `rand()` and append it to your table with another `union all`.

This might not be the best performing solution tho, but it will do it.

Example here: [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9635d2/971/0)